# LaTeX, Title of a research paper & Square root

Tags: math-mode, formatting, ieeetran

I'm writing a research paper, with LaTeX and IEEEtran.

I need to write the title of the paper.

The title is something like... "A novel 1 nV/sqrt(Hz) operational amplifier".

How would you **type** the sqrt stuff? Remember that this is the title, i.e. it will be Google-indexed, cited in other papers, ...

Which is, in your opinion, the best choice?

Option 1:

```
A novel 1 nV/rt-Hz operational amplifier
```

Option 2:

```
A novel 1 nV/sqrt(Hz) operational amplifier
```

Option 3:

```
A novel 1 nV/$\surd$Hz operational amplifier
```

Option 4:

```
A novel 1 nV/$\sqrt{\text{Hz}}$ operational amplifier
```

Option 5:

Say yours...

Comment: What is the physical unit of \sqrt{Hz} supposed to be? A root of inverse time?

Comment: Is writing `1 nV / (Hz)^{(0.5)}` a viable option? (Aside: What does taking the square root of a frequency mean?) Another idea: is there maybe a word (or word group) that could be employed as a descriptor in lieu of the formula? E.g., "A novel snazzy amplifier"?

Comment: looking at some literature in IEEE ( e.g. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/171168/),  they seem to write it in full mathematical symbols rather than using exponents as I would have expected (but then I come from a different field). With that being said, if you can use the `siunitx` package, I would use `\SI{1}{\nano \volt \per \sqrt{\hertz}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer V/sqrt(Hz) is the common way to describe the square root of voltage noise power spectral density (PSD). You have a signal, whose unit of measurement is X (volts in my example). You can compute its PSD, expressed in X^2/Hz, or, _better_, the square root of the PSD, expressed in X/sqrt(Hz), where _better_ is intended as "people know if 1 nV/sqrt(Hz) is high or low, while they do not know if 1e-18 V^2/Hz is high or low".

Comment: @Mico I would not use "extra" words. I would like to stress in the title the number I managed to obtain.

Comment: @PaoloMinotti: It does not really make sense unless, actually to use such strange units. (And I am a physicist)

Comment: This is off topic for this site (you are asking for authoring guidelines not how to implement any answer in TeX, however I'd use all mathematics or no mathematics, so definitely not `nV/$...`

Comment: @PaoloMinotti: It's a bit unfair to compare 1 nV to 1e-18 V^2. I bet "people" would find it much more difficult to understand 1e-9 V as well. Whereas 1 aV^2 seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: from an implementation-only point of view, @DavidCarlisle is correct that you should not mix math mode and non-math mode. looking at the package documentation of ieeetran, they don't seem to forbid users from using additional packages (even suggests a few) so `siunitx` should be safe. They do mention a possible way of formatting units on page 11 but it is really only to avoid the default formatting of the class in case is goes into small caps and doesn't help in math mode.

Comment: @PhilippImhof There's nothing unfair. That's how we electronic guys deal with this stuff. I'm just using standards. We talk about resolution using sqrt(PSD), simple. 1 nV is a minimum detectable voltage, 1 aV^2 is bullshit.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It makes sense to us, electronic guys. Trust me.

Comment: Is there any good soul that can suggest me a forum where this question won't be considered as off-topic?

Comment: @PaoloMinotti -- if you just change the question to ask how best to encode the "notation" part of the title, it would probably be considered on topic.  i assume that ieee, like ams, submits the bibliographic information for their journals to aggregators and indexers.  those "reprocessors" do have a really tough time indexing titles with lots of symbols and few words, but perhaps there is some post-processing by ieee editors to provide a more indexable form of the title for such uses.

Comment: Quite coincidentally, I noticed this question on electronics.SE in the sidebar: [Is measuring noise as V/√Hz obsolete?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282540/is-measuring-noise-as-v-%E2%88%9Ahz-obsolete) (asked a couple of hours before this question).